# ECMA6 Symbols primitive

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Currently i started working with JS ECMA6 for my personal web app,
but I am not sure about usage of Symbols
i.e. how can I make use of it?

I believe, they are tokens that serve as unique IDs. But I am not sure about its usage in web app development.

I am currently new to this standard, please provide your suggestions on it.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: And also http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html which gives some great real-world examples.

Comment: If you don't find any need for them, just don't use them. However, it might likely be useful to define custom iterators for your objects, so you'd use `Symbol.iterator` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols enable access control for object state. Symbols allow properties to be keyed by either string (as in ES5) or symbol. Symbols are a new primitive type. Optional description parameter used in debugging - but is not part of identity. Symbols are unique (like gensym), but not private since they are exposed via reflection features like Object.getOwnPropertySymbols.

```
var MyClass = (function() {

  // module scoped symbol
  var key = Symbol("key");

  function MyClass(privateData) {
    this[key] = privateData;
  }

  MyClass.prototype = {
    doStuff: function() {
      ... this[key] ...
    }
  };

  return MyClass;
})();

var c = new MyClass("hello")
c["key"] === undefined
```

It can be [referred here](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#symbols).
Here are few more links with nicely explained examples.(As already mentioned in comments section.)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol
- http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html